# Can I stop Backbone LayoutManager from generating extra <div>s?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-layout-manager

Given these templates:

```
<script id="template1" type="layout">
    Template 1 contents
</script>

<script id="template2 type="layout">
   Template 2 contents
   <section class="subview"></section>
</script>
```

And this view setup:

```
var View1 = Backbone.LayoutView.extend({
    template: "#template1"
});

var View2 = Backbone.LayoutView.extend({
    template: "#template2",
    views: {
        ".subview": new View1();
    }
});
```

I get this output:

```
Template 2 contents
<section class="subview"><div>Template 1 contents</div></section>
```

How can I instead get this output?

```
Template 2 contents
<section class="subview">Template 1 contents</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the following in your template keeping template 1's template the same:

```
<script id="template2 type="layout">
    Template 2 contents
</script>
```

Then in your view

```
var View2 = Backbone.LayoutView.extend({
    template: "#template2",
    beforeRender: function() {
        this.insertView(new View1());
    }
});

var View1 = Backbone.LayoutView.extend({
    template: "#template1",
    tagName: "section",
    className: "subview"
});
```

This would give you the following

```
<div>
   Template 2 contents
   <section class="subview">Template 1 contents</section>
</div>
```

I have found no other way of removing the 'div' unless by specifying a tagName attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If template1 had the contents:

```
<div class="myContents"></div>
```

then you may use jQuery's [unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to remove the  element in backbone layout managers [afterRender()](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/wiki/0.6.6-documentation) function

```
afterRender: function() {
    this.getView('.subView').$el.find('.myContents').unwrap();        
},
```